# How can I populated an IEnumerable<MyType>() on an object via configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I'm trying to populate the following object using the Option pattern:

```
public class MyParentPolicyOptions
{
    public IEnumerable<SomePolicySettings> SomePolicySettings { get; set; }
}
```

My config json looks like this:

```
{
  "MyParentPolicy": {
     "SomePolicies": [
     {
       "Name": "Default",
       "SomeSetting": 3,
       "IsHappy": false
     },
     {
       "Name": "Custom",
       "SomeSetting": 5,
       "IsHappy": true
     }
  ]
}
```

For the configuration I do something like this:

```
serviceConfigurationDefinition.Optional("MyParentPolicy", Validators.MyParentPolicyOptions());
```

At the point of building the configuration builder I can see it has my properties as expected in the following pattern:

```
{[MyParentPolicy:SomePolicies:0:Name, Default}]
{[MyParentPolicy:SomePolicies:0:SomeSetting, 3}]
{[MyParentPolicy:SomePolicies:0:IsHappy, false}]
```

However, after applying this configuration root to the ServiceConfigurationDefinition my actual MyParentPolicyOptions.SomePolicySettings is still null. It seems to work for other strongly typed objects but I can't get it to work for Lists / IEnumerables / arrays etc.

Just to add, I've just tried this with Dictionary<int, SomePolicySetting> in the hope that the automatic indexing would mean this was actually a dictionary type, but didn't work.

Comment: Use `List<SomePolicySettings>`.  `IEnumerable` is an interface and not a concrete type that can be instantiated. And the name of the property must match the name in the configuration, at least for automatic binding. `SomePolicies` is different than `SomePolicySettings`.

Comment: @Hazrelle - I tried this before, but tried it again for good measure and it still brings it up as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to get it from startup configuration

```
List<SomePolicySettings> settings=  configuration.GetSection("MyParentPolicy")
.Get<MyParentPolicy>().SomePolicies.ToList();
```

if you want to use it everywhere inside of your app , you can create a service

startup

```
services.Configure<MyParentPolicy>(configuration.GetSection("MyParentPolicy"));
services.AddSingleton<SomePolicySettingsService>();
```

service class

```
public class SomePolicySettingsService
{
    private readonly  List<SomePolicySettings> _somePolicySettings;

    public SomePolicySettingsService(IOptions<MyParentPolicy> myParentPolicy)
    {
         _somePolicySettings  = myParentPolicy.Value.SomePolicies;
    }
    
    public SomePolicySettings GetDefaultPolicySettings()
    {
        return _somePolicySettings.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Name=="Default");
    }
    public SomePolicySettings GetCustomPolicySettings()
    {
        return _somePolicySettings.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "Custom");
    }
}
```

or instead of creating and injecting service, you can just inject
" IOptions myParentPolicy"  in the constructor everywhere you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for the `serviceConfigurationDefinition.Optional()` method you use. In general I do it this way. You're right IEnumerable is working. The issue is somewhere else in your code. The following example is working.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices( (context,services) =>
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<MyParentPolicy>(context.Configuration.GetSection("MyParentPolicy"));
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
   .Build();
await host.RunAsync();

    public class MyParentPolicy
    {
        public IEnumerable<SomePolicySettings> SomePolicies { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomePolicySettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeSetting { get; set; }
        public bool IsHappy { get; set; }  
    }
```

and `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "MyParentPolicy": {
    "SomePolicies": [
      {
        "Name": "Default",
        "SomeSetting": 3,
        "IsHappy": false
      },
      {
        "Name": "Custom",
        "SomeSetting": 5,
        "IsHappy": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And finally retrieve the options with `IOptionsMonitor<MyParentPolicy>` for example:

```
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptionsMonitor<MyParentPolicy> options)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _parentPolicyOptions = options.CurrentValue;
        }
```